# Two ways of obtaining differential distribution using Mathematica do not match

Tags: distributions, dataset

Consider a set of data

```
dataset = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}
```

It contains ~200000 rows. I would like to obtain the pdf for x. I can do this, for example, using two ways:

1) To construct the bins:

```
 binsx1 = 
  Partition[Sort[#], Round[Length[#]/#2]] &[
   dataset[[All, 1]], BinsNumber];
xDistrTable = 
  Table[{(binsx1[[i]][[1]] + binsx1[[i]][[BinsHeight]])/
    2, BinsHeight/(
    binsx1[[i]][[BinsHeight]] - binsx1[[i]][[1]])}, {i, 
    1, BinsNumber, 1}];
```

2) Using double distribution function obtained using built-in Mathematica tools:

```
xyDistributionTemp = 
  SmoothKernelDistribution[dataset, 
   MaxExtraBandwidths -> 0];
xyDoubleDistribution[x_,y_] = 
 PDF[xyDistributionTemp, {x,y}]
xDistrTable1 = Table[{x,NIntegrate[xyDoubleDistribution[x,y],{y,ymin,ymax}]},{x,xmin,xmax,Deltax}]
```

Here, `BinsHeight, BinsNumber, xmin, xmax, Deltax, ymin, ymax` are some numbers.

The problem is that the distributions obtained by `xDistrTable` and `xDistrTable1` do not match each other (see a picture below). My first guess is that it is not enough data to obtain the double differential distribution, while it is enough statistics to get the single distribution function. However (my second guess), the problem also may be in my way to define the double distribution function.

Can anyone please give me an advise about the second guess?

P.S. Unfortunately I can not provide the dataset as it is too large.

[image]

Comment: Use the "Bounded" option in `SmoothKernelDistribution`.  Also, if you're interested in the pdf for a single variable, why would you want take the trouble to find the joint distribution and then integrate out the other variable?  Just use the single variable.

Comment: @JimB : thank you! Actually I need the double distribution. However, I use the single distribution as a cross-check.

Comment: @JimB : I have not found examples of using the "Bounded" option in Mathematica. Could you please recommend how to use it?

Comment: Look under Scope/Estimation with fixed domain (at least for *Mathematica* version 12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a univariate example using the "Bounded" option.

```
x = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[0.5, 0.5], 200000];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[x, 0.015, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Gaussian"}];
Plot[{PDF[BetaDistribution[0.5, 0.5], x],
  PDF[skd, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "Probability density"},
 PlotLegends -> {"True", "Estimated"}]
```

[image: Beta distribution and fit]